# PHP and MySql with date problem...?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, select

In my project I am using a table named "Compensation" like.....

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  |  receiver_Id   |  compensation   |      date           | 
|--------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1   |  5             |  50%            | 2011-02-15 12:15:00 | 
| 2   |  3             |  40%            | 2011-04-05 18:35:00 |
| 3   |  3             |  30%            | 2011-04-25 06:24:00 | 
| 4   |  5             |  45%            | 2011-04-21 19:05:00 |
| 5   |  5             |  60%            | 2011-04-30 12:05:00 |
.......................
```

Here the `date represents that the compensation is changed on that particular date`. For `receiver 5`, the compensation is 50%`before Feb 15 2011. And the compensation is`45%from`the date`15 Feb 2011 12:15:01 to 21 April 2011 19:05:00`. And so on....

Here When I create `invoice` for the month `APRIL 2011` for the `receiver 5`, I have to use the `compensation as 45%` till date `21 April 2011` and for `22 April 2011 to 30 April 2011 I have to use 60%` as compensation...

But How to get the compensation for a month or between 2 dates since the compensation may be modified multiple times in a month as id 4 and 5 shows.......

Please help me `writing SQL` for the above OR I have to make `changes` on the `table structure` to make it simple......?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be much easier when your table tracked both valid-from and valid-to dates:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Id  |  receiver_Id   |  compensation   |      date_from      |      date_to        |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|---------------------|
| 1   |  5             |  50%            | 2011-02-15 12:15:00 | 2011-04-21 19:05:00 | 
| 2   |  3             |  40%            | 2011-04-05 18:35:00 | 2011-04-25 06:24:00 | 
| 3   |  3             |  30%            | 2011-04-25 06:24:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
| 4   |  5             |  45%            | 2011-04-21 19:05:00 | 2011-04-30 12:05:00 | 
| 5   |  5             |  60%            | 2011-04-30 12:05:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
.......................
```

Then you can query:

```
SELECT * FROM compensations
    WHERE (date_to > $start_of_month OR date_to = 0 )
    AND date_from < $end_of_month;
```

Comment: well date_from and date_to are same as giving earlier and latter parameters to same field in BETWEEN clause wit query and if the compensation has not changed then it's currently valid compensation. Newest date is always valid in this structure so no need to change structure

Comment: +1. But I'd go with `SELECT * FROM compensations WHERE NOW() BETWEEN date_from AND date_to`

Comment: @Nemoden: The OP wants to query for all rows that apply to an entire month, not those who just apply to a single moment (like NOW())

Answer (score 1):

actually your date column looks more like date-time type not date but:

```
select * from yourtable where date between 'yourfirstdate' and 'yourlastdate'
```

however be aware that if you specify narrow gap in dates then your query can't return any results (even with Sander Marechal original solution) so a better option would be to check on larger gaps or always query 10 newest rows and apply the date filtering in code level.

Comment: This doesn't work. For example, your query would give zero results for Reciever 5 in the month of March (2011-03-01 through 2011-03-31) while in fact it should return row ID 1.

Comment: It's working like it is supposed to work giving out results between range of dates and not out of ranges as I explained. And as I can see now you have modified your query to reflect that change as well

Comment: Nope, it won't work. `SELECT * FROM compensations WHERE date BETWEEN 2011-03-01 AND 2011-03-31` -> `0 rows returned`. Correct behaviour according to the OP's description should return row ID `1`.

Answer (score 1):

the first sql will fetch the current month/year

the 2nd sql shows it hardcoded with a specific month/year

```
SELECT * FROM compensations
    WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW());


SELECT * FROM compensations
    WHERE YEAR(date) = '2011' AND MONTH(date) = '4';
```